# Xcode 5.1 "Expected identifier or "("" error

Tags: ios, xcode

I get this error after a curly bracket. I am writing an app for iOS. I am a beginner, so please explain thoroughly. Thanks!

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender;

{ //error happens here "Expected identifier or "(" "`

            UIImageView *img1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"batman.jpg"]];
                 img1.frame=CGRectMake(100, 75, 125, 351)

                 [self.view addSubview:img1];

          img1.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);
          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                                       delay:0.0
                                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                  animations:^{
                                      img1.transform =    CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/10), 1.7,1.7);

                                  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
               }];
           [img1 startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: - (IBAction)button1:(id)sender;\n
Please remove the semicolon ";"

Comment: Just to build on what @Vipul said, any time you write a method you don't want a semicolon at the end of the line. That's an objective-c syntax thing. And really any language built atop C for that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of you have misplaced "(" character in your class.

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender;
```

The `;` is not cause of this error, but you should not use it at the end of any method as it is a end point a statement.

**Cause of error**

Here you have place `"("` bracket above this method in your class.

Compiler starts compiling from the top of the class. If any syntax error is there compiler stops to compile remaining code from there.

So, it is clear that start checking your code from above this method. And remove extra `(` bracket and error will gone.